# convergence of a sequence of algebraic numers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let $\underline{\mathbf a}=(a_n)_n$ be a sequence of $K$ where $K$ is an algebraic number field. One considers that $K$ is embeded in $\mathbb C$. One assumes that the sequence $\underline{\mathbf a}$ converges towards $\beta\in K$. Suppose that for $\sigma\in\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)$, the sequence $(\sigma(a_n))_n$ converges, say towards $\gamma$. Is $\gamma$ equal to $\sigma(\beta)$?

Thanks in advance for any hints or solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. Take $K$ to be the field $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$ and $\sigma\in\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ such that $\sigma(a+b\sqrt{3})=a-b\sqrt{3}$, with $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$. Now consider $(a_n)$ a sequence of rational numbers converging to $\sqrt{3}$.

Then, $a_n-\sqrt{3}$ converges to $0$, but $\sigma(a_n-\sqrt{3})=a_n+\sqrt{3}$ converges to $2\sqrt{3}$, which isn´t $\sigma(0)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!